# Use regex in dataframe in order to extract part of columns

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I would need help in order to use regex on a R dataframe.

Here is the dataframe :

```
          Names
1                                                                                                [NW_019417116.1_2_3-HSPs_-__Canis_glabripennis]
2                                  [scaffold_29690_2-HSPs_-__Lopus_eremicus,scaffold_3037_+__Pig_sd,scaffold_144501_556-844_+__Lopus_eremicus]
3 [UDEW01029642.1_1-357_+__Falis_catus,scaffold_100683_331-631_+__Pig_sud,scaffold_209026_2-HSPs_+__Pig_sud,scaffold_220973_58-331_+__Pig_sud]
4                                                                       [scaffold_27087_+__Falis_catus,scaffold_77874_2-HSPs_-__Ratus_griseus]
```

and in the `df$Names` I would like to extract two parts for rows with `HSPs`(part with Species name which looks like (__Content_content):

for instance in `scaffold_77874_2-HSPs_-__Ratus_griseus` this in the `Ratus_griseus`
and the scaffold part, in `scaffold_77874_2-HSPs_-__Ratus_griseus` this in the `scaffold_77874` part

so I create two new columns and should get the desired output :

```
Names                                                                                                                                         Specie_name         Scaffold_name
[NW_019417116.1_2_3-HSPs_-__Canis_glabripennis]                                                                                               Canis_glabripennis  NW_019417116.1_2
[scaffold_29690_2-HSPs_-__Lopus_eremicus,scaffold_3037_+__Pig_sd,scaffold_144501_556-844_+__Lopus_eremicus]                                   Lopus_eremicus      UDEW01029642.1
[UDEW01029642.1_1-357_+__Falis_catus,scaffold_100683_331-631_+__Pig_sud,scaffold_209026_2-HSPs_+__Pig_sud,scaffold_220973_58-331_+__Pig_sud]  Pig_sud             scaffold_209026
[scaffold_27087_+__Falis_catus,scaffold_77874_2-HSPs_-__Ratus_griseus]                                                                        Rattus_griseus      scaffold_77874
```

So far I tried:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Scaffold_name = str_match(Names, regex(',(.*)_\\d+-HSPs'))[, 2], 
         Specie_name = str_extract(Names, ',(.*)_\\d+-HSPs_.__.*,|,(.*)_\\d+-HSPs_.__.*]|\\[*.[^,]*_\\d+-HSPs_.__.*\\]'),
         Specie_name = gsub(',','',Specie_name),
         Specie_name = gsub(']','',Specie_name),
         Specie_name = gsub('\\[','',Specie_name),
         Specie_name = gsub('.*__','',Specie_name)
         )
```

**here are the data**

```
structure(list(Names = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("[NW_019417116.1_3-HSPs_-__Canis_glabripennis]", 
"[scaffold_27087_+__Falis_catus,scaffold_77874_2-HSPs_-__Ratus_griseus]", 
"[scaffold_29690_2-HSPs_-__Lopus_eremicus,scaffold_3037_+__Pig_sd,scaffold_144501_556-844_+__Lopus_eremicus]", 
"[UDEW01029642.1_1-357_+__Falis_catus,scaffold_100683_331-631_+__Pig_sud,scaffold_209026_2-HSPs_+__Pig_sud,scaffold_220973_58-331_+__Pig_sud]"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `separate_rows` to split the 'Names' at the `,`, then clean the 'Names' column by removing the `[` and `]`, `separate` the 'Names' into two column by splitting at the `-[-+]__`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Names = as.character(Names)) %>%      
  separate_rows(Names, sep=",") %>% 
  mutate(Names = str_remove_all(Names, "\\[|\\]")) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Names, "HSPs")) %>%
  separate(Names, into = c('Scaffold_name', "Specie_name"),
          sep = "_[-+]__", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Scaffold_name = str_remove(Scaffold_name, "-HSPs"))
```

---

Or we could avoid the `filter/separate_rows` by directly extracting the substring and then `separate`

```
df %>%
  mutate(sub_name = str_extract(Names, "[[:alnum:]._]+-HSPs[^,]+")) %>% 
  separate(sub_name, into = c('Scaffold_name', 'Specie_name'),
           sep='-HSPs_[-+]__') %>%
  mutate(Specie_name = str_remove(Specie_name, "\\]"))
```

-output

```
                                                                                                                                       #Names
#1                                                                                                [NW_019417116.1_3-HSPs_-__Canis_glabripennis]
#2                                  [scaffold_29690_2-HSPs_-__Lopus_eremicus,scaffold_3037_+__Pig_sd,scaffold_144501_556-844_+__Lopus_eremicus]
#3 [UDEW01029642.1_1-357_+__Falis_catus,scaffold_100683_331-631_+__Pig_sud,scaffold_209026_2-HSPs_+__Pig_sud,scaffold_220973_58-331_+__Pig_sud]
#4                                                                       [scaffold_27087_+__Falis_catus,scaffold_77874_2-HSPs_-__Ratus_griseus]
#      Scaffold_name        Specie_name
#1  NW_019417116.1_3 Canis_glabripennis
#2  scaffold_29690_2     Lopus_eremicus
#3 scaffold_209026_2            Pig_sud
#4  scaffold_77874_2      Ratus_griseus
```